# Laravel Filter using various relations

Tags: php, laravel, filter, eloquent, laravel-6

I am doing a filter using relations here is my controller code:

```
$userList = User::with(['role' ,'userMetaData','userBet','userComission','userPartnership'])
    ->where('deleted', '=', '0')
    ->when($request->parent_id, function ($builder, $parent_id) {
        return $builder->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
    })
    ->when($request->role_id, function ($builder, $role_id) {
        return $builder->where('role', $role_id);
    })
    ->when($request->to && $request->from , function ($builder) use ($request) {
        return $builder->whereBetween('exposure_limit', [$request->from, $request->to]);
    })
    ->when($request->city, function ($builder) use ($request) {
        return $builder->whereHas('userMetaData', function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('city', $request->sport);
        });
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

In this case(in my code) i am trying to use `whereHas()` to filter a data from another table(within relations) by eloquent but it's something i am missing:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here in your case, when you use `Wherehas` to `userMetaData` it'll filter and gives you only those users who's has `city` as `$request->sport`..

In another case, you've used `with('userMetaData')` which means whatever users you got in filter return all `userMetaData`.

```
->when($request->city, function ($builder) use ($request) {
        return $builder->whereHas('userMetaData', function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('city', $request->sport);
        })->with(['userMetaData' => function($q) use ($request) {
            $q->where('city', $request->sport);
        }]);
    })
```

Remove `userMetaData` from `User::with(['role','userBet','userComission','userPartnership'])`

Comment: yes! the filter will be like that if someone enter city and role for example thing it will  filter like that those who have that role and city